# How to get multiple values using JSTL tags?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I have this button:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteuserbtn" value="${usr.idUser}" onclick="deleteUser(this.value)">Delete</button>`

That calls the function `deleteUser` once the button is clicked.

I would like to know how to send more than one value at the same time.

For example, if I want to send the `idUser` and the `userName`, how can I do it?.

I tried this but it's not working:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteuserbtn" value="${usr.idUser, usr.userName}" onclick="deleteUser(this.value)">Delete</button>`

I expect to receive the values in the same jsp page:

```
        function deleteUser(val1, val2) {
            alert(val1);
            alert(val2);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass your values under your function under `''` quotes else it will give you error not defined.So your button code will look like below :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="something" id="deleteuserbtn" onclick="deleteUser(this.value ,'${usr.idUser}','${usr.userName}')">
Delete</button>
```

**Demo Code** :

```js
function deleteUser(val1,val2,val3){
alert("val :"+val1 +" "+val2+" "+val3);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteuserbtn" value="something" onclick="deleteUser(this.value,'${usr.idUser}','${usr.userName}')">
    Delete</button>
```